# Why multiprocessing(Pool) is slower than serial run in python?

Tags: python, random, multiprocessing

I want to generate 5 sets of random numbers with size of (365, 100000) for monte carlo simulation. I try to use multiprocessing to increase the efficiency of generation. The test code is very simple as following. My laptop is Apple M1 Macbook pro with 8 cpu cores and 16GB memory. What I observed is that:

1. If I run the func test in a single for-loop for 8 iterations in one process, the time is about 4.88s. If I run the multiprocessing pool, the time is 4.36s. The performances are relatively similar. I don't see the efficiency increase from parallel run in multiprocessing.
2. I thought maybe the size of (365, 100000) is not computational intense. So the overhead cost exceeds the parallel gain at first. So I did another trial. I changed the size of (365, 100000) to (365, 1000000). Set num_cpu = 2 to create a pool with 2 working processed and only sent 2 tasks ([pool.apply_async(func=test, args=(i,)) for i in range(2)]. But the thing gets even worse.
3. If I run the func test in a single for-loop to generate (365, 1000000) standard normal
   random number for 2 iterations. It just needs 12 to 13 seconds. But if I run the
   multiprocessing pool and just sent 2 tasks, it needs more than 30s to get the results.

These results confused me a lot and I cannot find the reason. Could anyone gives me any suggestion and explaination. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
   
def test(i):
    print(f"process {i} starts"}
    np.random.seed(i)
    res = np.random.normal(0, 1, (365, 100000)
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_cpu = mp.cpu_count()
    start = time.perf_counter()
    pool = mp.Pool(num_cpu)
    res_list = [pool.apply_async(func=test, args=(i,)) for i in range(num_cpu)]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    res = [r.get() for r in res_list]
    print(end - start)

    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(num_cpu):
        test(i)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start)
```

Comment: I suspect a lot of the time spent in the multiprocessing case is simply due to pickling/unpickling those huge arrays for transport between processes - work which is unnecessary in the single-process case.  Do you get more reasonable times if `test()` does a `return None` instead?

Comment: @jasonharper Yes!! Thank you very much! I get reasonable times if it returns nothing. I don't fully familiar with concept of pickling and unpickling.  Is the func test() pickled at the start of multiprocess and res (if the return of the func is res) is unpickled at the end of process? And if I want to get the generated random number, I must bear this pickling/unpickling cost? No other better ways? Thank you agian for you explaination!

Comment: "pickling" is serializing the data into a stream so it can be sent between processes. It's only needed to return the result; it can be avoided when _starting_ the process because `fork()` copies all memory contents, so children can (if each process is only running one previously-known input) start out already knowing the input, but not having a way to pass the output back to their parent in-process (because it's no longer the same process as the parent). Whereas if you want to use a process for inputs that aren't known when it's started, they need to be pickled going in too.

Comment: The function itself isn't (and can't be) pickled - it gets shared between processes either via forking, or re-executing the module in the new process, depending on platform.  The parameters get pickled going in, and the return value gets pickled on the way back; a more realistic example of multiprocessing would be doing a lot more work for each element of the returned array, so that the pickling overhead would be proportionally much smaller.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks Charles! I understand the mechanism!

Comment: @jasonharper. Pretty useful! Thanks! So just for example, if I take the average of the ndarray I generated in test() and just return a float (the average value). The pickling overhead will be reduced a lot?

Comment: Right, the pickling overhead would be pretty much unmeasurable in that case.